# Dart - How to a change the color of my raisedButton after clicking in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

so i've been struggling to change the color of my button from green to red for my flutter app. Most of the online resources are confusing me. This is my following code.

```
new RaisedButton(key:null, onPressed:buttonPressed,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child:
                      new Text(
                      "10:00 A.M. - 11:00 A.M.",
                        style: new TextStyle(fontSize:15.0,
                        color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                        fontFamily: "Roboto"),
                      )
                    ),void buttonPressed(){
    }
```

I want to click it and it turn green, or even better. Click it, so it turns gray. Then click another button that states "confirm", and it would make all the grey buttons that have been clicked red. Regardless, I'm just trying to understand how to make the button change color after being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you need to do is,

- Make RaisedButton color a class-level variable instead of constant as you have now.
- Initialize that variable to some color value in `initState` method.
- In the `onPressed` handler of RaisedButton, do the following:

  - Change that variable to some color value of your liking.
  - Trigger Repaint (so that the new color gets painted) i.e. call `setState` method.

Last but not least, you'll need to have all the code above part of a stateful widget.

Hopefully, it's clear enough, let us know if you'd need some code sample as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool turnToRed = false;
bool colorIsGreen = true;

RaisedButton(key:null, onPressed: (){
   setState((){
     colorIsGreen = !colorIsGreen;
   });
},
                color: colorIsGreen ? Colors.green :turnToRed ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
                child:
                  new Text(
                  "10:00 A.M. - 11:00 A.M.",
                    style: new TextStyle(fontSize:15.0,
                    color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                    fontFamily: "Roboto"),
                  )
                ),
RaisedButton(key:null, onPressed: (){
   setState((){
     turnToRed = !turnToRed;
   });
},
                color: Colors.red
                child:
                  new Text(
                  "Confirm",
                    style: new TextStyle(fontSize:15.0,
                    color: const Color(0xFF000000), 
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                    fontFamily: "Roboto"),
                  )
                ),
```